# attribute test now returning 2 elements in enzyme 3

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have just upgraded from enzyme 2 to 3 and the following test that previously returned 1 element now returns 2:

```
  it('should find element', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent/>);

    expect(wrapper.find('[name="element"]')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

I found [this](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#element-referential-identity-is-no-longer-preserved) link that seems to suggest that this is the expected behaviour.

It does not say why this is good or how should I now be writing my tests?